# generate list of letters

Tags: c

I'm trying to generate a list of letters, then im gonna separate to multiple files...

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void) 
{ 
    FILE *fp;
    char x[6] = "aaa00";
    int i, k, j, l, m;
    i = k = j = l = m = 0;
    fp=fopen("c:\\file.txt", "wb");

    while(i<26){    //when this loops is over all will be generated, letter x[0]
        i++;
        while(k<26){ //letters x[1]
            k++;
            while(j<25){ //letters x[2]
                j++;
                /*while(l<9){ //numbers 0 - 9
                    l++;
                    while(m<9){ //numbers 0 - 9
                        m++;
                        fwrite(x, sizeof(x[0]), sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]), fp);
                        x[4]++;
                    }
                    x[3]++;
                }
                l = 0;*/
                x[2]++;
            }
            x[1]++;
            j = 0;
            x[2] = 'a'; //reset
        }
        x[0]++;
        k = 0;
        x[1] = 'a'; //reset
    }

    return 0;
}
```

list saves to a 10mb file in total, I might need to separate to multiple files

Comment: any help would be appreciated. thanks for the comment..

Comment: Use `char x[5] = {'a', 'a', 'a', '0', '0'};`. The const string is not modifiable and will lead to a segmentation fault.

Comment: @lightalchemist There is no const string. `char x[6] = "aaa00";` is an array. `"aaa00"` is just the initialization.

Comment: You have to reset both the counters (`m`, `l`, etc.) and the contents of your string (`x[3]`, `x[4]`) for all loops, except the outer loop. (Conceptually, I'd set these values before the loop as an initialisation rather than as resetting them afterwards, but that's probably a matter of taste)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple nested loops are ugly and unmanagable. When you all of a sudden need more characters, you need to add loops. Also, did I mention they're ugly?

This problem calls for recursion, so here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                  

void generate(char *str, int i)                                                                     
{                                                                                                   
    printf("%s\n", str);                                                                            

    char c = str[i];                                                                                
    if ((i < 3 && c == 'z') || (i <= 4 && c == '9'))                                                
        ++i;                                                                                        

    if (i == 5)                                                                                     
        return;                                                                                     

    ++str[i];                                                                                       
    generate(str, i);                                                                               
}                                                                                                   

int main()                                                                                          
{                                                                                                   
    char str[] = "aaa00";                                                                           
    generate(str, 0);                                                                               
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you are trying to generate all the possibilities, something like this, perhaps:

```
int i,j,k,l,m;

for(i=48; i<58; i++)

    for(j=48; j<58; j++)

        for(k=97; k<123; k++)

            for(l=97; l<123; l++)

                for(m=97; m<123; m++)

                    printf("%c%c%c%c%c\n",k,l,m,i,j);
```

The range `48 to 58` & `97 to 123` represent the ascii values.

For eg: you may replace `for(i=48; i<58; i++)` with `for(i='0'; i<='9'; i++)` for more clarity.

Comment: You could use char constants in place of numbers (`'a'` vs `97`) to make it slightly more clear.

Comment: I mean't it as a pseudocode, but ended up with above. Thanks, I'll update.

Comment: Note: in both cases (char constants or numerics) it will fail on a [noncontiguous character platform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC). I.e it isn't portable (not that the OP likely cares).

Comment: @WhozCraig I wonder if anyone should care. Though its worth of knowing (probably), there are some funny quotes on the page you link: "EBCDIC An alleged character set used on IBM dinosaurs. It exists in at least six mutually incompatible versions, all featuring such delights as non-contiguous letter sequences and the absence of several ASCII punctuation characters fairly important for modern computer languages". =) EDIT: Ok, there is an OS, I see, that has latest stable release dated to 2011, so it is probably still in actual use at some places.

Comment: @luk32 If you ever have to write portable server software for AS/400 or OS/390, *and* Solaris, AIX, Linux, and HPUX, I assure you you'll care (and I have, and I never did before, but I do now). Portability is engrained in me as a result, and though it often means very little to very many, it means very much to very few. I'm sorry if even mentioning it raised a hackle. (and fwiw, most of the US Government mainframes are zSeries S/390, and they care *plenty*).

Comment: @WhozCraig No, please take no offence, I just liked the quotes in the wiki. You must admit though, this is pretty exotic. I think it is important to note, that there is this implicit assumption in this solution. And that it will not work for systems that I would call equivalent of native tribes in amazonian jungle. But they are there. Not denying that. I work mostly with computational stuff, where efficiency matters and this is not portable, even when the code is. Thus, maybe I am inclined to be more lenient with solutions that work good on most systems, even at cost of ultimate portability.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void inc_str(char *str){
    int index, carry;
    for(index = strlen(str)-1;index>=0;--index){
        if(str[index] == 'z'){
            carry = 1;
            str[index] = 'a';
        } else if(str[index] == '9'){
            carry = 1;
            str[index] = '0';
        } else {
            carry = 0;
            ++str[index];
        }
        if(carry == 0)break;
    }
}

int main(){
    char x[6] = "aaa00";

    while(1){
        printf("%s\n", x);
        if(strcmp(x, "zzz99")==0)
            break;
        inc_str(x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix your code, make sure that you reset the counters and string contents for every loop:

```
int xmain(void) 
{ 
    char x[6] = "aaa00";
    int i, k, j, l, m;
    i = k = j = l = m = 0;

    while(i<26){    //when this loops is over all will be generated, letter x[0]
        i++;
        while(k<26){ //letters x[1]
            k++;
            while(j<26){ //letters x[2]
                j++;
                while(l<10){ //numbers 0 - 9
                    l++;
                    while(m<10){ //numbers 0 - 9
                        m++;
                        printf("%s\n", x);
                        x[4]++;
                    }
                    m = 0;
                    x[3]++;
                    x[4] = '0'; //reset
                }
                l = 0;
                x[2]++;
                x[3] = '0'; //reset
            }
            x[1]++;
            j = 0;
            x[2] = 'a'; //reset
        }
        x[0]++;
        k = 0;
        x[1] = 'a'; //reset
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That code is quite long, because you use doubled-up data: The counters `i` to `l` and the contents of the string. You have to keep them in sync, which might mess this up - and actually has in your example. Loxxy's code is much more straightforward.

But the problem is, of course, interesting and you can see a pattern emerging in your code: When a number exceeds its limit, the next one gets incremented, like in an odometer. You could generalise this code to gerenate all strings between two upper and lower limits:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const char *lo = "aaa00";
    const char *hi = "zzz99";
    char buf[6] = {0};
    int len;

    strcpy(buf, lo);
    len = strlen(buf);

    for(;;) {
        int n = len;

        printf("%s\n", buf);
        buf[n - 1]++;
        while (n-- && buf[n] > hi[n]) {
            if (n == 0) goto done;
            buf[n] = lo[n];
            buf[n - 1]++;
        }
    }
    done: return 0;
}
```

If you don't like the odometer approach, you can use Loxxy's straightforward nested loops in a recursive style to generalise the solution:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_combo(const char *from, const char *to, char buf[], int n)
{
    int c;

    if (from[n] == '\0' || to[n] == '\0') {
        printf("%s\n", buf);
    } else {
        for (c = from[n]; c <= to[n]; c++) {
            buf[n] = c;
            print_combo(from, to, buf, n + 1);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char buf[6] = {0};

    print_combo("aaa00", "zzz00", buf, 0);

    return 0;
}
```